# How to intercept multiple backticks notation in OpenAI response

Tags: javascript, openai-api, backticks

I have written a simple OpenAI based chatbot in JS, but i want to intercept the backticks indicating the language in the chatbot response... in both opening and close
I have tried multiple regexes, i came out with the following:

````
fetch(API_URL, requestOptions)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
messageElement.textContent = data.choices[0].message.content.trim();
// Find and replace tml, ss, and avascript
messageElement.textContent = messageElement.textContent.replace(/```(html|css|javascript)(.*?)/gs, '$2');
messageElement.textContent = messageElement.textContent.replace("```", "");
})
.catch(() => {
messageElement.classList.add("error");
messageElement.textContent = "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again.";
})
.finally(() => chatbox.scrollTo(0, chatbox.scrollHeight));
````

The problem is it works well but at the end of the code the last backticks closing line is not replaced. I.E. if i ask for a css navbar code, i get:

> CSS (salvato in un file chiamato "style.css"):
>
> nav {   background-color: #333; }
>
> nav ul {   list-style-type: none;   margin: 0;   padding: 0;
> overflow: hidden; }
>
> nav li {   float: left; }
>
> nav li a {   display: block;   color: white;   text-align: center;
> padding: 14px 16px;   text-decoration: none; }
>
> nav li a:hover {   background-color: #111; }  ```

Anybody has an idea on how to solve this?
Thanks in advance.
Alex.

Comment: Does ChatGPT return your code in properly enclosed backticks? From the example, it looks like only the ending backticks are added and not the opening ones, but it could be a StackOverflow formatting issue.

Comment: Why do you use `"```"` instead of `/```/` or `/```/g`? The first is not a regex!

Comment: shame on me, it was so obvious :( thank you i guess my mind was so dizzy after 3 hours spent arranging the functions, and i got lost in a glass of water :-\

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bergi's comment i found out i had used the wrong approach for the second replace.
Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Might be a bit overblown, but the function `replaceAll` below allows to pass in a mapping of characters and their replacement values and produces a new function that accepts an incoming string wherein characters are replaced.

````js
const DATA = 'A string with ```backticks { some: foo; }\ntest::after { content: "bar"; }```';

const replaceAll = (replacementMapping) => {
  const replaceChars = Object.entries(replacementMapping);
  return (inputString) => {
    return replaceChars.reduce(
      (s, [oChar, nChar]) => s.replace(new RegExp(oChar, 'g'), nChar),
      inputString
    );
  };
};

const escaper = replaceAll({
  '`': '\\`',
  '"': '\\"'
});

console.log(escaper(DATA));
````